# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I made a recyclerview in a Fragment, with code like this, before I made this, in the usual activity, and I tried to make it in Fragment Activity, but it happened even error

```
public class GaweanFragment extends BaseFragment {

@BindView(R.id.rv_gawean_fragment)
RecyclerView rv_gawean_fragment;
@BindView(R.id.prbLoading)
ProgressBar prbLoading;
@BindView(R.id.txvUser)
TextView txvUser;
@BindView(R.id.txvDescription)
TextView txvDescription;
@BindView(R.id.btnSubmit)
Button btnSubmit;
@BindView(R.id.lnrNoList)
LinearLayout lnrNoList;

@BindDrawable(R.drawable.ic_obs_on_white_36px)
public Drawable observationOn;
@BindDrawable(R.drawable.ic_obs_off_white_36px)
public Drawable observationOff;
@BindDrawable(R.drawable.ic_sc_on_white_36px)
public Drawable storecountOn;
@BindDrawable(R.drawable.ic_sc_off_white_36px)
public Drawable storecountOff;

@BindString(R.string.error_no_internet)
public String errorInternet;
@BindString(R.string.request_failed)
public String requestFailed;
@BindString(R.string.error_location_not_found)
public String errorLocationNotFound;
@BindString(R.string.please_wait)
public String pleaseWait;
@BindColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
public int colorPrimary;
@BindColor(R.color.grey_600)
public int colorGrey;

@BindString(R.string.no_order_list_please_order)
public String errorNoList;

private LatLng myLocation;
private Boolean isObservation = true;
private Boolean isStoreCount = false;
private Boolean isMapReady = false;

private GaweanPresenter presenter;
private List<Job> gaweanJobs;
private Job selectedJob;
private android.location.Location locA;
private Float radiusKilometer;

@Override
protected int getLayout() {
    return R.layout.f_gawean;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initRV();

    presenter = new GaweanPresenter(this);
    gaweanJobs = new ArrayList<>();

    if (ThemeUtil.getThemes() == ThemeUtil.THEME_OBSERVATION) {
        loadObservation();
    } else {
        loadStoreCount();
    }

}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    gaweanJobs = new ArrayList<>();
    if (ThemeUtil.getThemes() == ThemeUtil.THEME_OBSERVATION) {
        loadObservation();
    } else {
        loadStoreCount();
    }
}

@Override
public void busHandler(RxBusObject.RxBusKey busKey, Object busObject) {
    switch (busKey) {
        case MAP_READY:
            myLocation = (LatLng) busObject;
            if (myLocation != null) {

                isMapReady = true;

                if (isObservation) {
                    presenter.getAssignList(GaweanPresenter.OBSERVATION, Double.toString(myLocation.latitude), Double.toString(myLocation.longitude));
                    presenter.getApplyList(GaweanPresenter.OBSERVATION, Double.toString(myLocation.latitude), Double.toString(myLocation.longitude));
                }

                if (isStoreCount) {
                    presenter.getAssignList(GaweanPresenter.STORE_COUNT, Double.toString(myLocation.latitude), Double.toString(myLocation.longitude));
                    presenter.getApplyList(GaweanPresenter.STORE_COUNT, Double.toString(myLocation.latitude), Double.toString(myLocation.longitude));
                }
            }
            break;

        case SELECT_PLACE:
            Place place = (Place) busObject;

            for (int i = 0; i < gaweanJobs.size(); i++) {
                if (place.getId().equals(gaweanJobs.get(i).getIdJob())) {
                    selectedJob = gaweanJobs.get(i);
                    break;
                }
            }

            showCheckInDialog();

            break;

        case LOCATION_CHANGE:
            myLocation = (LatLng) busObject;
            if (myLocation != null) {
                if (gaweanJobs.size() > 0)
                    loadList();
            }
            break;
    }
}

public void initRV() {
    final LinearLayoutManager llManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    llManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rv_gawean_fragment.setLayoutManager(llManager);
}

public void loadList(List<Job> jobList) {
    gaweanJobs.addAll(jobList);

    Collections.sort(gaweanJobs, new Comparator<Job>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Job lhs, Job rhs) {
            // -1 - less than, 1 - greater than, 0 - equal, all inversed for descending

            Double leftDistance = 0d;
            Double rightDistance = 0d;
            if (lhs.getStoreDist() != null) {
                try {
                    leftDistance = Double.parseDouble(lhs.getStoreDist());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (lhs.getAreaDist() != null) {
                try {
                    leftDistance = Double.parseDouble(lhs.getAreaDist());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (rhs.getStoreDist() != null) {
                try {
                    rightDistance = Double.parseDouble(rhs.getStoreDist());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (rhs.getAreaDist() != null) {
                try {
                    rightDistance = Double.parseDouble(rhs.getAreaDist());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return rightDistance > leftDistance ? -1 : (rightDistance < leftDistance) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    });

    rv_gawean_fragment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    lnrNoList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    prbLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    JobListAdapter jobListAdapter = new JobListAdapter(getContext(), gaweanJobs, myLocation);
    rv_gawean_fragment.setAdapter(jobListAdapter);
    rv_gawean_fragment.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);

    if (gaweanJobs.size() > 0) {

    }
}

public void loadList() {
    rv_gawean_fragment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    lnrNoList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    prbLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    rv_gawean_fragment.setAdapter(new JobListAdapter(getContext(), gaweanJobs, myLocation));
    rv_gawean_fragment.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
}

public void showNoList(String message, String action) {
    if (gaweanJobs.size() == 0) {
        rv_gawean_fragment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lnrNoList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        prbLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (!message.equals(""))
            txvDescription.setText(message);
        btnSubmit.setText(action);
    }
}

private void showCheckInDialog() {
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

    locA = new android.location.Location("");
    locA.setLatitude(myLocation.latitude);
    locA.setLongitude(myLocation.longitude);

    radiusKilometer = Float.parseFloat(selectedJob.getRadiusMeter()) / 1000;

    String name = "";
    String date = "Deadline: " + DateUtil.format(DateUtil.format(selectedJob.getDueDate(), "yyyy-MM-dd"), "EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy");

    String description = selectedJob.getDescription();

    if (selectedJob.getName() != null && !selectedJob.getName().equals("")) {
        name = selectedJob.getStoreName() + "\n";
    } else {
        name = selectedJob.getAreaName() + "\n";
    }

    String title = "";
    switch (selectedJob.getIdJobType()) {
        case "2":
            title = "Barcode Scan";
            break;
        case "3":
            title = "Area Survey";
            break;
        default:
            title = "Observasi";
    }

    new MaterialDialog.Builder(getContext())
            .backgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
            .title(title)
            .titleColor(colorPrimary)
            .content(name + description + "\n\n" + date + "\n\n" + "Ingin memulai job ini?")
            .contentColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_600))
            .positiveText("Ya")
            .positiveColor(colorPrimary)
            .negativeText("Tidak")
            .negativeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_600))
            .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    if (selectedJob.isApporved()) {
                        //STORE COUNT
                        if (selectedJob.getIdJobType().equals("1")) {
                            float distance = 0f;

                            if (selectedJob.getAreas() != null) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < selectedJob.getAreas().size(); i++) {
                                    Area area = selectedJob.getAreas().get(i);

                                    if (area.getDist() != null) {
                                        if (i == 0) {
                                            Location locB = new Location("");
                                            locB.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(area.getLatitude()));
                                            locB.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(area.getLongitude()));
                                            distance = locA.distanceTo(locB) / 1000;
                                        }


                                        if (Double.parseDouble(area.getDist()) < distance) {
                                            Location locB = new Location("");
                                            locB.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(area.getLatitude()));
                                            locB.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(area.getLongitude()));
                                            distance = locA.distanceTo(locB) / 1000;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            if (distance <= radiusKilometer) {

                            } else {

                            }
                        } else if (selectedJob.getIdJobType().equals("2")) {

                        } else if (selectedJob.getIdJobType().equals("3")) {
                            List<LatLng> areas = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (Area area : selectedJob.getAreas()) {
                                areas.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(area.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(area.getLongitude())));
                            }

                            if (PolyUtil.containsLocation(myLocation, areas, true)) {

                            } else {



                                float distance = 0f;

                                if (selectedJob.getAreas() != null) {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < selectedJob.getAreas().size(); i++) {
                                        Area area = selectedJob.getAreas().get(i);

                                        if (area.getDist() != null) {
                                            if (i == 0) {
                                                Location locB = new Location("");
                                                locB.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(area.getLatitude()));
                                                locB.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(area.getLongitude()));
                                                distance = locA.distanceTo(locB) / 1000;
                                            }

                                            if (Double.parseDouble(area.getDist()) < distance) {
                                                Location locB = new Location("");
                                                locB.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(area.getLatitude()));
                                                locB.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(area.getLongitude()));
                                                distance = locA.distanceTo(locB) / 1000;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                if (distance <= 0.5) {

                                } else {


                                }


                            }
                        } else if (selectedJob.getIdJobType().equals("4")) {

                        }


                    }
                }
            })
            .show();
}

public void showLoading() {
    prbLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    lnrNoList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    rv_gawean_fragment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public void loadObservation() {



    isObservation = true;
    isStoreCount = false;

    if (isMapReady) {
        presenter.getAssignList(GaweanPresenter.OBSERVATION, Double.toString(myLocation.latitude), Double.toString(myLocation.longitude));
        presenter.getApplyList(GaweanPresenter.OBSERVATION, Double.toString(myLocation.latitude), Double.toString(myLocation.longitude));
    }


}

public void loadStoreCount() {

    isObservation = false;
    isStoreCount = true;

    if (isMapReady) {
        presenter.getAssignList(GaweanPresenter.STORE_COUNT, Double.toString(myLocation.latitude), Double.toString(myLocation.longitude));
        presenter.getApplyList(GaweanPresenter.STORE_COUNT, Double.toString(myLocation.latitude), Double.toString(myLocation.longitude));
    }

}

@OnClick(R.id.btnSubmit)
public void onClickSubmit(Button v) {
    if (v.getText().toString().equals("Coba Lagi")) {
        if (ThemeUtil.getThemes() == ThemeUtil.THEME_OBSERVATION) {
            loadObservation();
        } else {
            loadStoreCount();
        }
    } else {
        HomeActivity.startActivity(getActivity());
    }
}
```

but, i have problem like this, in my recycler view, this is the Log

```
Process: com.mogawe.mosurvei, PID: 4807
                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at com.mogawe.mosurveibeta.view.fragment.menu.GaweanFragment.initRV(GaweanFragment.java:215)
                                                                   at com.mogawe.mosurveibeta.view.fragment.menu.GaweanFragment.onCreate(GaweanFragment.java:130)
```

the error is on this line of code

```
rv_gawean_fragment.setLayoutManager(llManager);
```

actually what caused this error, and how to debug it. Maybe just it, i hope you can help me in this error, thanks

Comment: Could you put part of the code of your basefragment when you do the butterknife binding?

Comment: yes i can

 `@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
        Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            this.bus = ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).getBus();
    }`

Comment: so you don't bind your views using ButterKnife?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is

> When you call `initRV` in `onCreate` method .The Activity may be not created .

So you can call it in your `onActivityCreated` method .
And `rv_gawean_fragment.setLayoutManager(llManager);` will work ok in `onActivityCreated` method .

You can do this .

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    initRV();
}
```

Comment: I've tried to do it, but initRV () method seems unreadable, do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize butterknife before using views in your layout so add this line to **onViewCreated** method **ButterKnife.bind(this, view);** and replace your **onCreate** code in on activity create method

Hope this helps!